# How to get my facebook account friends userids fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am running below query but it display like 10 20 results even though i have thousands of friends

how can i get all friends userids ?

```
SELECT uid1  FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()
```

Comment: You can't. The API just return the friends that are actually using the app

Comment: @WizKid so you can not get your own profile friends list ? I am the app owner.

Comment: @WizKid if have user id can i query whether he is my friend or not ?

Comment: You can get the your friends that are using the app. Whether who is your friend? If they are not using the app what would you query against?

Comment: @WizKid the reason why i am asking simple. Lets say i have 1000 friends at my profile. And then i make a post. Then i want to see which of my friends liked my post. However not all my friends uses this app i created. So it is not possible for me to find out which of my friends liked that post ?

Comment: No it is not if they are not using your app

Comment: @WizKid however when i list the post like this facebook shows who is my friend and who can i add friend : https://www.facebook.com/browse/likes?id=798977736804548&actorid=198765706825757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every info is available with the API. And as Wizkid commented, you only get friends who authorized your App too. But you should not use FQL for this, it´s a simple call to [/me/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends) with the Graph API.

You can find more information in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

There is also a very detailed answer about that topic in this thread: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)